# why Z score values are correlated in opposite direction of raw value?

Tags: correlation, z-score

I am trying to find the correlation between age at onset of diabetes and Body Mass Index of patients. When i performed correlation test in R I get a positive "r" between age and BMI.. but when the same BMI is converted to z-scores I am getting negative correlation. How would interpret this result. Can someone please help.. Following is my results from R

> WITH BMI

```
Call:
lm(formula = age ~ bmi, data = temp)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.3649 -1.8292 -0.2815  1.3361  8.6716 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  5.76891    0.45737  12.613   <2e-16 ***
bmi          0.23689    0.02382   9.944   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.427 on 508 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1629,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1613 
F-statistic: 98.89 on 1 and 508 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

> WITH BMI Z SCORE

```
Call:
lm(formula = age ~ z, data = temp)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.4553 -1.9565 -0.1407  1.4838  7.0065 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  10.0316     0.1188  84.433  < 2e-16 ***
z            -0.7271     0.1439  -5.054 6.05e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.588 on 508 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.04787,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.046 
F-statistic: 25.54 on 1 and 508 DF,  p-value: 6.055e-07
```

> This is the code to calculate Z-score. The code is in PERL

http://pastie.org/10843530

[image]

[image]

[image]

Following is the regression result of log transformed age vs z , actual BMI and gender

```
lm(formula = log(age) ~ NZ + bmi + gender, data = temp)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.50191 -0.07392  0.01485  0.08512  0.46986 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.731636   0.046103  15.869   <2e-16 ***
NZ          -0.305887   0.010358 -29.532   <2e-16 ***
bmi          0.079247   0.002353  33.681   <2e-16 ***
genderM     -0.022121   0.012759  -1.734   0.0836 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.1416 on 506 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6981,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6963 
F-statistic:   390 on 3 and 506 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Comment: You should show how you compute `z` from `bmi`... or better, re-examine how you compute it, and spot your mistake.

Comment: To compute the z scores, I have another reference data set with Age Gender and Body Mas Index (BMI). I computed mean(SD) BMI of Age and gender specific subsets of reference data .. Then subtracted the raw BMI (of my data set) from the computed Mean and then divided by SD.

Comment: First: why do you have *another* data set? Second: the mistake is that you subtract the raw BMI from the mean. This reverses signs. You should do it the other way around: subtract the mean from the raw data.

Comment: @Stephan Kolassa, Thanks for the reply. I use different reference data set for the z score calculation because, my sample has all diabetic patients.. and I need non diabetic healthy people as reference to calculate z-score. And the second : I am very sorry that's a typo .. I actually subtracted the mean from the raw data only..

Comment: Ah. But if your raw data and your $z$ scores come from different populations, you have different regressions - why would you expect the correlations to have the same sign? Plus, I probably am still not understanding what you do. It seems to me ilke you are regressing some people's age on *other* people's $z$-transformed BMIs (judging from your explanation of the "other dataset"). Why would you do that?

Comment: @StephanKolassa, I think choosing national or international representative data set is a standard practice.. thats why I chose a national dataset as a reference for calculating z score.

Comment: So you do something like `z = (mu_ref - bmi) / sd_ref`. No wonders the sign changes, the higher `bmi` is, the lower `z` is. Why not try  `z = (bmi - mu_ref) / sd_ref` instead?

Comment: Elvis, Yes that what I did.. subtracted the mean from the raw data only which is `z = (bmi - mu_ref) / sd`

Comment: Yes, but why do you regress person A, B, C's age on person X, Y, Z's $z$-transformed BMIs? I don't see how this makes sense.

Comment: You wrote "subtracted the raw BMI (of my data set) from the computed Mean and then divided by SD", that is `(mu_ref - bmi) / sd_ref`. Please double check.

Comment: @StephanKolassa, following is from research paper `BMI z-scores are calculated relative to an external reference (whether national or international) and not to an internal reference. The effect of this is that more than 5% of the population could be, for example, above the 95th percentile of BMI-for-age. Whereas, if an internal reference were used, exactly 5% of every sample would be above the 95th percentile, and the specific BMI cut point designating the 95th percentile would not be the same across samples. For this reason, BMI z-scores are based on an external reference`

Comment: @StephanKolassa I don’t think arshad regresses on other persons z-scores. He/She just wants an effect with units "x standard deviations from the mean", and for standard deviation and mean (s)he uses a healthy population, this sort of makes sense.

Comment: @StephanKolassa, As Elvis said,  Thats what I did..

Comment: That's why I'm so confused about all this talk about "other datasets", when the code includes a data.frame called `temp` with a variable called `age` in both cases. It seems like these are actually two different data.frames. Correct? In which case, we have two different regressions from two different populations, and I'd say there is any number of reasons why we could get different correlation signs. For instance, are both populations age-matched? The relationship between age and BMI may be very different between adults and young children.

Comment: @StephanKolassa, sorry for the confusions.. the regression is done on the same data set. I used the reference dataset only to get the mean and sd .. which I computed age and gender specific. I used this mean and SD to calculate age and gender matched z scores in my dataset..

Comment: Ah, thank you. That makes things a lot clearer. What I'm *now* not understanding is what you mean by "age and gender matched $z$ scores". Could you perhaps edit your post to include a plot of `z` against `bmi`, as well as the specific code you used to calculate `z`?

Comment: @StephanKolassa, by "age and gender matched z scores", I meant.. I calculated mean BMIs for each age and gender stratified.. ex: I group all people in age 15 and gender Male from my reference data set.. then compute mean and SD BMI for this group. Then using this mean and SD I calculate z score for the male patients in the age of 15 in my staudy data set by (BMI of the patient - MEAN from the ref data)/SD of ref data.. I edited my original query with plot and codes to calculate z score

Comment: Great, with the plots it’s now beginning to be clear and interesting. You have a very clear relation between bmi (measured at onset?) and age at onset. The bmi and the z score (using a reference depending on age and sex) are well correlated. However the relation between z and age at onset is in the other direction!

Comment: I am thinking out loud. The higher the bmi, the higher the age at onset. Is that something expected? BTW, is that type I or type II diabetes? I assume type I, as there are many young patients, am I right? Early onset could mean "more genetic than environment (including bmi)", hence this positive correlation, late onset implying a bad environment, hence a high bmi. However when you consider z, which is more ore less the bmi corrected by age+sex, you find that high z correspond to an early onset. However this could be an artifact, the distribution of the age is right skewed.

Comment: Dis you try to log transform the age? And to put z and bmi together in a regression? Shouldn't the variable sex ebe include as a predictor as well?

Comment: Thank you. Is this the bmi measured at onset? I feel that this question is slowly turning into a question of epidemiology...

Comment: yes, BMI was measured at onset.

Comment: So early onset means high z value (high BMI for an individual of this age) but low BMI -- well, yes, the younger you are, the lower your BMI, that seems to make sense, especially for the range of ages in your sample. It makes sense, don’t you think? So the (slightly overweight) guys you have in your incident diabetes sample have a bmi correlated with their age. The fact that the younger they are, the chubbier, doesn’t counterbalance this.

Comment: This now seems very clear to me. I hope I convinced you. I’ll edit my answer below. Thank you for this question which is a good example of how tricky real life problems can be!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will first address a reformulation of your question, which is statistically relevant: if $\def\cov{\text{cov}}\cov(X_1, X_2) > 0$, $\cov(X_2, Y) > 0$, is it possible that $\cov(X_1, Y) < 0$ ?

The answer is yes, although it can seem counterintuitive. Here is an example of positive definite matrix exhibiting the desired behavior:

```
> D <- matrix( c(1, 0.2, -0.1, 0, 0.9, 0.3, 0, 0, 0.8), nrow=3 ) 
> D
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  1.0  0.0  0.0
[2,]  0.2  0.9  0.0
[3,] -0.1  0.3  0.8
> D %*% t(D)
     [,1] [,2]  [,3]
[1,]  1.0 0.20 -0.10
[2,]  0.2 0.85  0.25
[3,] -0.1 0.25  0.74
```

So you can have $\cov(X_1, X_2) = 0.2$, $\cov(X_2, Y) = 0.25$ and $\cov(X_1, Y) = -0.1$.

This case corresponds to a situation where

- $X_1$ has variance $1$,
- $X_2 = 0.2\> X_1 + \varepsilon$ with $\varepsilon$ independent of $X_1$ and
  $\def\var{\text{var}}\var(\varepsilon) = 0.9^2$
- $Y = -0.1 \> X_1 + 0.3 \>\varepsilon + \varepsilon' = -0.16 \> X_1 + 0.3 \> X_2 + \varepsilon'$ with $\varepsilon'$ independent of $X_1, \varepsilon$ and $\var(\varepsilon') = 0.8^2$.

More generally, this will not be possible if $Y$ is independent of $X_1$ conditionally to $X_2$.

Now back to your problem: in your sample, early onset implies high $z$ value (i.e. high BMI for an individual of this age) but low BMI -- well, yes, the younger you are, the lower your BMI (cf [this chart](http://gofigureweightloss.com/BMI/body-mass-index-children-bmi.gif) for the evolution of the BMI in the age range in your sample). So the (slightly overweight) guys you have in your incident diabetes sample have a BMI correlated with their age. The fact that the younger they are, the chubbier, doesn’t counterbalance this.

I think it could be interesting to try to produce a chart of BMI for incident diabetes cases, as a function of age, and to compare it to the above linked chart. I think this will help to grasp what’s happening in these data.